# What is the difference between "I am red in the face" and "I get red in the face"

Tags: difference, verbs

My student asked me this question. Seems I couldn't explain it to him. I need help. I'm not even sure "get red in the face" is correct.

Answer (score 3):

There definitely is a difference between the two phrases:

> I am red in the face.

This phrase refers to the speaker's **current state**. At the moment of speaking, the speaker is red in the face.

> I get red in the face.

This refers to **a habit** or **a fact**. It will usually be accompanied by a *when*-phrase or something similar:

> Whenever he asks me a question I get red in the face.

The verb *get* here has the meaning of *become*. It indicates a **change in the speaker's state**. The speaker goes from normal to being *red in the face*.
However, it is not a change that is going on at the moment of speaking. It is one that happens whenever the *when*-phrase is true. If it is going on at the moment of speaking, the speaker would most likely use a progressive tense:

> I am getting red in the face.

The above phrase may sound a bit odd though. Being *red in the face* means you are feeling embarrassed or ashamed. It may just be me, but it would sound odd to say that you are becoming embarrassed or ashamed. Something may trigger embarrassment or shame, but those two seem to me rather immediate reactions instead of a process.

Comment: I now understand the difference clearly.. Thanks Sander

Answer (score 2):

"I am red in the face" refers to your present state of being.  It means that at this moment, your face is red.  "I get red in the face" can refer to two things.  It can mean that you are currently going from a normal face to a red face, or it can mean that your face often becomes red.